# How to Query a Dataset with multiple tables from XML file in VB.NET to populate a DataGrid

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagrid

This is my first time posting here and I am definitely new to VB.NET so if I do something wrong please forgive me.

I am trying to create a simple GUI to update an XML we use for drive mappings for login scripts.  No comments please on if this is a bad way to do login scripts.

I have a form that has a combobox and datagrid on it.  What I need to do is populate the combobox with the OU name values which I have done already.  Now what I can't get done is populating the DataGrid with the mappings for each OU.  The thing I can't figure out is when I read my XML into a Dataset it creates two Tables, OU and mappings. What I would like to do is when I pick an OU from the ComboBox have it populate the DataGrid with just the mappings from that OU.  There is a common OU_Id's field that is in both tables.  I think this should be as easy as a select query on the two tables but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get that done.  Please help me.

Here is the format of the XML file.

```
<OUs>
    <OU name="ABC - NYO">
        <mapping path="" drive="F:"/>
        <mapping path="\\nyopr901\apps_prod" drive="G:"/>
        <mapping path="" drive="I:"/>
        <mapping path="" drive="J:"/>
        <mapping path="" drive="K:"/>
        <mapping path="" drive="L:"/>
        <mapping path="" drive="M:"/>
    </OU>
    <OU name="ABC - CAL">
        <mapping path="" drive="F:"/>
        <mapping path="\\nyopr901\apps_prod" drive="G:"/>
        <mapping path="" drive="I:"/>
        <mapping path="" drive="J:"/>
        <mapping path="" drive="K:"/>
        <mapping path="" drive="L:"/>
        <mapping path="" drive="M:"/>
    </OU>
</OUs>
```

Here is my  code so far.

```vb
Public Class frmLoginScriptMaintenance
Public dsDM As New DataSet()

Private Sub frmLoginScriptMaintenance_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Read in XML from file
    DriveMappings()
    For i = 0 To dsDM.Tables("OU").Rows.Count - 1
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(dsDM.Tables("OU").Rows(i).Item(1))
    Next
    ' Bind DataSet to Data Grid
    'grdData.DataMember = "mapping"
    'grdData.DataSource = dsPubs
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim dsDrives As New DataSet()
    Dim expression As String
    ' Read in XML from file
    ' Bind DataSet to Data Grid
**THIS IS WHERE I AM GOING WRONG**
    grdData.DataMember = "mapping"
    grdData.DataSource = dsDM.Tables(1).Select(**NOT SURE WHAT SHOULD GO HERE**)
End Sub

Public Function DriveMappings() As DataSet
    dsDM.ReadXml("DriveMappings.xml")
    Return dsDM
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your XML is loaded into the `DataSet`, a relationship is created between the two tables.  You can navigate this relationship using the [`DataRow.GetChildRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3y2s99c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

So, for example, you can go from an OU to the related mappings using something like this:

```vb
Dim ouRow As DataRow = dsDM.Tables("OU").Rows(0)
' OU_mapping is the default name for the relationship that is generated
Dim mappingRows() as DataRow = ouRow.GetChildRows("OU_mapping")
```

You can use `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex` to find the appropriate row in the OU table in the `SelectedIndexChanged` method.

**UPDATE**

As you saw, binding to an array of `DataRow` doesn't really give you what you want.  Instead, if you change your `ComboBox` and `DataGridView` bindings, the relationship should be tracked automatically between the `ComboBox` selection and the `DataGridView` rows.

```vb
Private Sub frmLoginScriptMaintenance_Load(...
    ' Read in XML from file
    DriveMappings()
    ' Bind the ComboBox to the OU table, showing the name column
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dsDM
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "OU.name"
    ' Bind the DataGridView to the mapping table, via the relationship, to show
    ' just the rows related to the selected OU
    grdData.DataSource = dsDM
    grdData.DataMember = "OU.OU_mapping"
End Sub
```

You should not need the `ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged` handler at all.

*Note: tested in a .NET 4.5.2 project with standard `ComboBox` and `DataGridView` components.*

Comment: I can't get this to work.  I am much closer.  Here is what i changed.

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim ouRow As DataRow = dsDM.Tables("OU").Rows(0)
        ' OU_mapping is the default name for the relationship that is generated
        Dim mappingRows() As DataRow = ouRow.GetChildRows("OU_mapping")
        grdData.DataSource = mappingRows
    End Sub

Now the datagrid is putting the right amount of rows but it has column names like RowError,RowState,Table,HasErrors

Comment: Hmm, yes - binding to an array of `DataRow` probably doesn't look too nice!  Oops. :-)  I'll update the answer to show how you can bind things and have it track the master/detail relationship automagically.

Comment: Mark, Thank you so much.  I don't know why I didn't think to look if the Combobox was able to use a data source, that is awesome.  I would +1 your answer except apparently I am too new to do so yet.  Your help is greatly appreciated.  This little project has got me excited to get back into coding.  It's been so many years since I did any programming.